# customize command response with prefix for error messages only

Tags: linux, bash, shell, scripting

I'm writing a bash script that retrieves apparent disk usage for a list of folders:

```
du -sb /logs
du -sb /var/xyz
du -sb /usr/local/bin
```

If directories exists, output is:

```
98983493 /logs
1489872 /usr/local
```

...but if it doesn't, output may be:

```
> cannot read directory `/logs': Permission denied 
> cannot access `/usr/local': No such file or directory
```

I have to parse the response; can I prefix error message to make that easier? I'd rather deal with a single error identifier than varying ones; something like this...

```
**error** cannot read directory `/logs': Permission denied 
**error** cannot access `/usr/local': No such file or directory
```

Scripting is definitely my weak point, and I admit nothing has been tried aside from a quick search.

**Limitations**

- Can't use sed/awk or like tools; only standard linux commands.
- File system is read-only; can't write.

Comment: Diagnostic messages go to standard error, not standard output. Maybe that's already enough?

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish this with bash by redirecting stder into a [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution):

```
(
    echo stderr >&2
    echo stdout
    echo stdout2
    echo stderr2 >&2 
) 2> >( sed 's/^/**error**/')
```

```
stdout
stdout2
**error**stderr
**error**stderr2
```

It appears you lose the interleaving of stdout and stderr, but you keep their relative ordering.